# Definition of "Normal topological space"

Tags: general-topology, definition

I found this definition but i don't know if it is correct or not ?

"A topological space X is normal if for every pair of closed disjoint sets A and B of X there exists $f: X\to [0; 1]$ continuous, such that $f(A) = \{0\}$ and $f (B) = \{1\}$"

I need a reference please if it is correct .

Comment: Isn't $f$ supposed to be continuous here? Otherwise I don't see how this says anything about the topology of $X$.

Comment: @JustinBenfield yes $f$ is supposed continuous

Comment: Based on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_space, it seems that your definition is for a *perfectly* normal space.

Comment: Yes, the definition you found is correct; see [Urysohn's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urysohn%27s_lemma). But where did you find it? **PLEASE SOURCE YOUR QUOTATION.**

Comment: @JustinBenfield - Perfectly normal requires that $f^{-1}(0) = A$ and $f^{-1}(1) = B$. The conditions here are weaker, and by Urysohn's lemma are equivalent to the usual (and IMO, preferable) definition of normal.

Answer (score 2):

You may take this as the definition of "normal", but is unusual. The standard definition is this:

A topological space $X$ is normal if for every pair of disjoint closed sets $A$ and $B$ of $X$ there exist disjoint open subsets $U$ and $V$ of $X$ such $A \subset U$ and $B \subset V$ (in other words, if any two disjoint closed subsets $A$ and $B$ of $X$ have disjoint open neighborhoods).

Urysohn's lemma (see bof's comment) says that your definition is equivalent to the standard definition. It was proved by Pavel Samuilovich Urysohn in 1925.